# Fundamental Theorem of calculus to find a function of the form of two functions

Tags: calculus

[image]> Find a function $f$ and a positive number $\beta$ such that

> $$ \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{\beta} {f(t)\ln (t) dt = \exp(y) -\ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\beta} \right) - \pi } $$
> for all $y>0$.

Hi, I have no idea how to solve this question, but it seems relatively simple yet I haven’t seen anything with two functions in it before. Please help if you can, thanks in advance!

Edit: I’ve had a great reply but I just don’t understand how taking the derivative of the integral doesn’t just give you the function contained within the integral? Somehow d/dy remains and we have beta and (y)^(1/2) that somehow appear from nowhere? If anyone could explain this would be great! I’ve added a file highlighting what I’m confused about if it helps.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Don't use picture in the question session. Use MathJax formatting for mathematical expressions. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hint: Take the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

**Background on FTC and Derivatives of Definite Integrals**

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that given a function $g$ and an antiderivative $G$ (so $G'=g$), we have

$$ \int_a^b g(t) dt = G(b) - G(a) . $$

This relationship holds even if the limits $a$ and $b$ are functions of some other variable, say $y$:

$$ \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} g(t) dt = G\left(b(y)\right) - G\left(a(y)\right) . $$

Now, if we differentiate both sides with respect to $y$, we have

$$ \frac{d}{dy} \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} g(t) dt = \frac{d}{dy} \left[ G\left(b(y)\right) - G\left(a(y)\right) \right] $$

$$ \frac{d}{dy} \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} g(t) dt = g\left(b(y)\right)b'(y) - g\left(a(y)\right)a'(y) , $$

where $b'$ and $a'$ appear due to the chain rule being applied when we calculate the derivatives of $G\left(b(y)\right)$ and $G\left(a(y)\right)$, respectively.

Note, if either $a$ or $b$ is a constant function, then its derivative is 0 and that term disappears from the right-hand side.

**Solution to Question**

In this problem, $g(t) = f(t)\ln(t)$, $a(y) = \sqrt{y}$, and $b(y) = \beta$.

We start by taking the derivative with respect to $y$ on both sides:

$$ \frac{d}{dy}\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{\beta} {f(t) \ln(t) dt} = \frac{d}{dy} \left[ e^y-\ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\beta} \right) - \pi \right] $$

Using the FTC on the left, we get

$$ f(\beta)\ln(\beta)\frac{d}{dy}\beta - f\left(\sqrt{y}\right)\ln \left(\sqrt{y}\right)\frac{d}{dy}\sqrt{y} = e^y - \frac{1}{2y} $$

Since $\beta$ is a constant, $\frac{d}{dy}\beta = 0$:

$$ - \frac{f\left(\sqrt{y}\right) \ln \left(\sqrt{y}\right)}{2\sqrt{y}} = e^y - \frac{1}{2y} $$

Let $t = \sqrt{y}$:

$$ - \frac{f(t) \ln (t)}{2t} = e^{t^2} - \frac{1}{2t^2} $$

$$ \Rightarrow f(t) = -\frac{1}{\ln (t)}\left( 2te^{t^2} - \frac{1}{t} \right) $$

Now, to find $\beta$, we plug $f(t)$ back into the integral:

$$ \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{\beta} {- \frac{1}{\ln (t)}\left( 2te^{t^2} - \frac{1}{t} \right) \ln(t) dt} = e^y-\ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\beta} \right) - \pi $$

$$ -\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{\beta} { \left( 2te^{t^2} - \frac{1}{t} \right) dt} = e^y-\ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\beta} \right) - \pi $$

$$ -\left[e^{t^2} - \ln(t) \right]_\sqrt{y}^{\beta} = e^y-\ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\beta} \right) - \pi $$

$$ \left[e^{y} - \ln\left(\sqrt{y}\right) \right] - \left[e^{\beta ^2} - \ln(\beta) \right] = e^y-\ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\beta} \right) - \pi $$

$$ e^{y} - \ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\beta}\right) - e^{\beta ^2} = e^y - \ln \left( \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\beta} \right) - \pi $$

$$ e^{\beta ^2} = \pi $$

$$ \beta = \sqrt{\ln (\pi)} $$

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the help :))

Comment: While applying FTC there was no need to deal with $d\beta/dy$. The FTC says that the derivative equals $-(1/2\sqrt{y})f(\sqrt {y}) \log\sqrt{y} $.

Comment: @HeatherNapthine updated the solution with a bit more on the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to respond to your additional questions, hope this helps!